Filling a model in two columns with scrolling
need to arrange the model in 4 rows and two displayed columns, the remaining columns are accessible by scrolling the scroll bar.
my code:
Window {
    width: 300
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        width: 300
        height: 480

        ListModel {
            id: dataModel

            ListElement {
                color: "orange"
                text: "1"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "skyblue"
                text: "2"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "orange"
                text: "3"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "skyblue"
                text: "4"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "orange"
                text: "5"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "skyblue"
                text: "6"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "orange"
                text: "7"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "skyblue"
                text: "8"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "orange"
                text: "9"
            }
            ListElement {
                color: "skyblue"
                text: "10"
            }

        }

        GridView {
            id: view

            anchors.margins: 10
            anchors.fill: parent

            model: dataModel


            flow: GridView.FlowTopToBottom
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 150
                height: 100
                color: model.color

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                    text: model.text
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}

I tried to do it through listView and tableview. but it didn't work to arrange it in two columns with scroll

I think you are close. I would add the following properties to your GridView:
GridView {
    // ...
    // clip, ScrollBar and cell dimension corrections
    clip: true
    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn }
    cellWidth: 150
    cellHeight: 100
    // ...
}

You can Try it Online!

The third column should not be displayed until you start scrolling. and the scroll is not moving

cellWidth: 150 will correctly place and size your columns.

You can use a GridLayout. As a start, change your GridView to this:
Flickable {
        id: flickable
        width: parent.width;
        height: 400

        clip: true

        contentWidth: view.width
        contentHeight: view.height

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{
        }

        GridLayout {
            id: view

            columns: 2
            Repeater {
                model: dataModel

                Rectangle {
                    width: 150
                    height: 100
                    color: model.color

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                        text: model.text
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


scrolling should be horizontal, not vertical. And there should be 4 lines. How to do it

@user27668421 you just said 4 rows and 2 columns. How is that horizontal?

the model should scroll horizontally to the third column
